# Extracting colors using OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

in this question I am using using Udacity's code [here](https://gist.github.com/hristo-vrigazov/a859364e97714360bd04d8a5e6989776)

I tried to convert the code from python to C++,

I did it in two different ways with two different results, the second one behaviour is more acceptable, I believe.

In the first approach, I split the image into 3 channels RGB, then I used threshold on each one of then I added the result together to get a mask, then I used the mask on the original image  like the python code(or did i do something wrong)

```
cv::Mat mask, result;
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpg");
std::vector<cv::Mat> thresholds(3);
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
std::vector<int> RGB = { 200,200,200 };
cv::split(image, channels);
cv::threshold(channels[0], thresholds[0], RGB[0], 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(channels[1], thresholds[1], RGB[1], 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(channels[2], thresholds[2], RGB[2], 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);
mask = thresholds[0] | thresholds[1] | thresholds[2];
image.copyTo(result, mask);
cv::imshow("result", result);
```

when i tried to merge the channels instead of

```
mask = thresholds[0] | thresholds[1] | thresholds[2];
```

I merged the mask like

```
merge(thresholds, mask);
result = image & mask; // i tried & | -
```

In the second approach, I converted the image to greyscale then I get remove the noises then, I use the threshold on them then I used the result to mask the original image

```
cv::Mat mask, result,gray;
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("test.jpg");
cv::Mat channel;
cv::cvtColor(image, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::medianBlur(gray, channel, 5);
cv::threshold(channel, mask, 200, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY);
image.copyTo(result, mask);
```

here's the python piece I am trying to convert

```
thresholds = (image[:,:,0] < rgb_threshold[0]) \
            | (image[:,:,1] < rgb_threshold[1]) \
            | (image[:,:,2] < rgb_threshold[2])
color_select[thresholds] = [0,0,0]
plt.imshow(color_select)
```

Even though the first way is similar to python code, the output when value is 200 is no way close however, the result from the second approach is almost identical to the python result.

Can someone explain  why the first openCV C++ approach doesn't get similar result to openCV
python(when it should) and the second one does

Comment: In the python code, the result image is color image RGB, in the first c++ approach, the output is gray (1 channel), right? 
In python,  you apply threshold to each channel R G B separately , keep RGB format and `imshow()`.
In the 1st c++ approach, you separate R G B, apply threshold to each channel then bitwise (merge) 3 channels into a single channel (gray image). It is not correct way, you can try `cv::merge()` to merge those 3 channels into single RGB image before `imshow()`. 

Note: I have not tested on my own yet.

Comment: the output!! as in the final output? No, the output of the first approach is a 3 channel image. I did what you said in one of my first tries by using merge instead of bitwise or but the result was worse,  unless I was doing it wrong, I  updated my question  and  showed couple of my failed attempts